# Maven local repository failed to resolve artifact

Tags: maven, repository, local

I am trying to rebuild a dev environment to make some changes to a web app that was developed back in 2009. I am have having trouble with maven and crystal reports artifacts in the local repository. The jar files are definitely in the local repository. I have a copy of the old pom files and also a backup of the .m2 local repo. When I run mvn clean compile I get the following output:
Note: underscores to stop urls.

```
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/businessobjects/sdks/jrc_11_8_0_11_8_6_v1371/ReportViewer/1.0/ReportViewer-1.0.pom
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/businessobjects/sdks/jrc_11_8_0_11_8_6_v1371/webreporting/1.0/webreporting-1.0.pom
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/businessobjects/sdks/jrc_11_8_0_11_8_6_v1371/jrcerom/1.0/jrcerom-1.0.pom
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/businessobjects/sdks/jrc_11_8_0_11_8_6_v1371/serialization/1.0/serialization-1.0.pom
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/businessobjects/developer/crystalreportsforeclipse/doc_1.0.6.v1371/1.0/doc_1.0.6.v1371-1.0.pom
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/businessobjects/developer/crystalreportsforeclipse/nl1_1.0.6.v1371/1.0/nl1_1.0.6.v1371-1.0.pom
[INFO] [compiler:compile] [INFO] Compiling 168 source files to C:\WorkSpaces\CKDProject\CKDProject\core-domain\target\classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building web [INFO]    task-segment: [clean, compile]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [clean:clean] [INFO] Deleting directory C:\WorkSpaces\CKDProject\CKDProject\web\target
[INFO] [resources:resources]
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 5 resources

Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/businessobjects/sdks/jrc_11_8_0_11_8_6_v1371/CrystalContentModels/1.0/CrystalContentModels-1.0.pom
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/businessobjects/sdks/jrc_11_8_0_11_8_6_v1371/CrystalDatabaseConnectors/1.0/CrystalDatabaseConnectors-1.0.pom
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/businessobjects/sdks/jrc_11_8_0_11_8_6_v1371/CrystalExporters/1.0/CrystalExporters-1.0.pom
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/businessobjects/sdks/jrc_11_8_0_11_8_6_v1371/CrystalExportingBase/1.0/CrystalExportingBase-1.0.pom
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/businessobjects/sdks/jrc_11_8_0_11_8_6_v1371/CrystalFormulas/1.0/CrystalFormulas-1.0.pom
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/businessobjects/sdks/jrc_11_8_0_11_8_6_v1371/CRDBJavaServerCommon/1.0/CRDBJavaServerCommon-1.0.pom
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/businessobjects/sdks/jrc_11_8_0_11_8_6_v1371/CRDBXMLExternal/1.0/CRDBXMLExternal-1.0.pom
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/businessobjects/sdks/jrc_11_8_0_11_8_6_v1371/CRDBXMLServer/1.0/CRDBXMLServer-1.0.pom
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/businessobjects/sdks/jrc_11_8_0_11_8_6_v1371/CrystalCharting/1.0/CrystalCharting-1.0.pom
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/businessobjects/sdks/jrc_11_8_0_11_8_6_v1371/CrystalCommon/1.0/CrystalCommon-1.0.pom
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/businessobjects/sdks/jrc_11_8_0_11_8_6_v1371/CrystalReportingCommon/1.0/CrystalReportingCommon-1.0.pom
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/businessobjects/sdks/jrc_11_8_0_11_8_6_v1371/CrystalQueryEngine/1.0/CrystalQueryEngine-1.0.pom
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/businessobjects/sdks/jrc_11_8_0_11_8_6_v1371/CrystalReportEngine/1.0/CrystalReportEngine-1.0.pom
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/businessobjects/sdks/jrc_11_8_0_11_8_6_v1371/keycodeDecoder/1.0/keycodeDecoder-1.0.pom
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/businessobjects/sdks/jrc_11_8_0_11_8_6_v1371/MetafileRenderer/1.0/MetafileRenderer-1.0.pom
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/businessobjects/sdks/jrc_11_8_0_11_8_6_v1371/rpoifs/1.0/rpoifs-1.0.pom
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/businessobjects/sdks/jrc_11_8_0_11_8_6_v1371/Concurrent/1.0/Concurrent-1.0.pom
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/businessobjects/sdks/jrc_11_8_0_11_8_6_v1371/ebus405/1.0/ebus405-1.0.pom
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/businessobjects/sdks/jrc_11_8_0_11_8_6_v1371/icu4j/1.0/icu4j-1.0.pom
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/businessobjects/sdks/jrc_11_8_0_11_8_6_v1371/URIUtil/1.0/URIUtil-1.0.pom
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/businessobjects/sdks/jrc_11_8_0_11_8_6_v1371/jrcadapter/1.0/jrcadapter-1.0.pom
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/jmaki/ajax-wrapper-comp/1.8.1/ajax-wrapper-comp-1.8.1.pom
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/local/sun/java/net/jaxws-spring/1.8/jaxws-spring-1.8.pom
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/local/xbean-spring/2.8/xbean-spring-2.8.pom
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/businessobjects/sdks/jrc_11_8_0_11_8_6_v1371/Concurrent/1.0/Concurrent-1.0.jar
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/businessobjects/sdks/jrc_11_8_0_11_8_6_v1371/ebus405/1.0/ebus405-1.0.jar
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/businessobjects/sdks/jrc_11_8_0_11_8_6_v1371/icu4j/1.0/icu4j-1.0.jar
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/businessobjects/sdks/jrc_11_8_0_11_8_6_v1371/URIUtil/1.0/URIUtil-1.0.jar
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/businessobjects/sdks/jrc_11_8_0_11_8_6_v1371/jrcadapter/1.0/jrcadapter-1.0.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Failed to resolve artifact. Missing:
----------
1) com.businessobjects.sdks.jrc_11_8_0_11_8_6_v1371:Concurrent:jar:1.0  
Try downloading the file manually from the project website.   Then,
install it using the command: 
      mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.businessobjects.sdks.jrc_11_8_0_11_8_6_v1371 -DartifactId=Concurrent -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file   Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
      mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=com.businessobjects.sdks.jrc_11_8_0_11_8_6_v1371 -DartifactId=Concurrent -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]   Path to dependency:        1) root.project:web:war:1.0     2)
com.businessobjects.sdks.jrc_11_8_0_11_8_6_v1371:Concurrent:jar:1.0
```

My pom file has the following lines for the various jar files required for crystal reports:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.businessobjects.sdks.jrc_11_8_0_11_8_6_v1371</groupId>
    <artifactId>rasapp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version> 
</dependency>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks, Jason

Answer (score 3):

Are you absolutely certain that you have the correct repository backup?

> The jar files are definitely in the local repository

Unless you're configured Maven to look elsewhere the missing file should be located here:

```
$HOME/.m2/repository/com/businessobjects/sdks/jrc_11_8_0_11_8_6_v1371/Concurrent/1.0/Concurrent-1.0.jar
```

## Explanation

Obviously Maven is reporting missing dependencies.

The following dependency is a commercial jar which explains why it doesn't exist in the default [Maven Central repository](http://search.maven.org/).

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.businessobjects.sdks.jrc_11_8_0_11_8_6_v1371</groupId>
<artifactId>Concurrent</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version> 
</dependency>
```

at some distant point in time, this dependency was shoe horned into the local repositoy using something like the following command:

```
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.businessobjects.sdks.jrc_11_8_0_11_8_6_v1371 -DartifactId=Concurrent -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=Concurrent.jar
```

Using this mechanism to manage 3rd party dependencies, is the best way to guarantee lots and lots of fun in reproducing a build on a different machine....

In my experience there is no substitute for using a Maven repository manager:

- [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/)
- [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/home/v_artifactory_opensource_overview)
- [Archiva](http://archiva.apache.org/).

In fact if this more than a once off activity might be an idea to setup a properly managed repository for these missing dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first find out in which repository is your "rasapp" jar located and then add that repository url in your settings.xml and this jar will get downloaded.